# remove this unidentified character "\" from string python

Tags: python

I want to remove this string "\". But i can't remove it because it's needed to do "\t or \n". Then i try this one """"\"""". But the python still don't do anything. I think the binary is not get this string. This is the code

```
remove = string.replace(""""\"""", " ")
```

And I want to replace

```
"\workspace\file.txt" become "workspace file.txt"
```

Anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: So you just want to get rid of a backslash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to replace a backslash, but since Python uses backslashes as escape characters, you actually have to escape the backslash itself.

```
remove = str.replace("\\", " ")
```

DEMO:

```
In [1]: r"\workspace\file.txt".replace("\\", " ")
Out[1]: ' workspace file.txt'
```

Note the leading space. You may want to call `str.strip` on the end result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslash, as it has special meaning in strings.  Even in your original string, if you leave it like that, it'll come out...not as you expect:

```
"\workspace\file.txt" --> '\\workspace\x0cile.txt'
```

Here's something that will break the string up by a backslash, join them together with a space where the backslash was, and trim the whitespace before and after the string.  It also contains the correctly escaped string you need.

```
" ".join("\\workspace\\file.txt".split("\\")).strip()
```

Comment: Why do you use split and join here, rather than replace? Is there some optimization?

Comment: Since I wasn't using a raw string, I had to work around the fact that both the original string was jacked, and that you'd get leading whitespace if you only did the join.

Comment: Does `" ".join(["", "some", "text"])` yield leading whitespace? I figured it ignored empty strings. Interesting.

Comment: `join` will use every entry in the list, including the empty string.  So yes, it's going to generate a blank string by virtue of there being an empty string in the list.

Comment: @AdamSmith It would be slower

Answer (score 0):

View this way you can archive this,

```
>>> str = r"\workspace\file.txt"
>>> str.replace("\\", " ").strip()
'workspace file.txt'
>>>
```